# Count consecutive repeated elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list `{a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,d,e,f,f,f,a,a,a}`, how can one count the number of consecutive repeated elements efficiently? The desired result would be `{2,3,5,1,1,3,3}`.

Comment: `list={a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,d,e,f,f,f,a,a,a};Length /@ Split[list]`

Comment: The above works because default behavior of Split is **splits list into sublists consisting of runs of identical elements**

Comment: In the good old days of procedural Fortran programming , we solved such problems like this `lis={a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,d,e,f,f,f,a,a,a};
current=lis[[1]];
count=0;
First@Last@Reap[
  Do[
     If[lis[[counter]]===current,
        count++
     ,
        Sow[count];
        count=1;
        current=lis[[counter]]
     ],
     {counter,1,Length@lis}
     ]
]`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLSCP.png)  not like now, by just calling one builtin function. programmers  have it easy these days :)

Comment: `SequenceCases[lis, {p : x_ ..} :> Length[{p}]]` where `lis = {a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, c, c, d, e, f, f, f, a, a, a};`  although not a contender in the speed category.